# MQTT publishing to AWS IoT Core

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, mqtt, aws-iot, paho

I'm trying to publish data in a dataframe (originally in a txt file) to AWS IoT Core using paho-mqtt. My publish script is setup as follows:

```
# paho mqtt
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

clientID = "iotconsole-somenumber-0"
broker = "alphanumeric-ats.iot.us-west-1.amazonaws.com"
port = 8883

pub = mqtt.Client(clientID)
pub.tls_set("certs/AmazonRootCA1.pem", certfile = "certs/a0c94969f1e7d914d6fe54425d772e8d4611a4710d460e9f56374ea0afd4f67f_certificate.pem.crt", keyfile = "certs/a0c94969f1e7d914d6fe54425d772e8d4611a4710d460e9f56374ea0afd4f67f_private.pem.key")
pub.connect(broker, port)
pub.publish("awsiot_test", dataframe, qos = 1)
```

But, when I run this script I get the following error. I think I'm doing something wrong with my thing certs. But can't zero in on it.

```
  File ~\PyProj\projfolder\code.py:9 in <module>
    pub.tls_set("certs/AmazonRootCA1.pem", certfile = "certs/a0c94969f1e7d914d6fe54425d772e8d4611a4710d460e9f56374ea0afd4f67f_certificate.pem.crt", keyfile = "certs/a0c94969f1e7d914d6fe54425d772e8d4611a4710d460e9f56374ea0afd4f67f_private.pem.key")

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\paho\mqtt\client.py:796 in tls_set
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile, keyfile_password)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I thought it was a cert file -/_ issue or an extension issue. But, haven't found a solution yet. How do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: The code that is failing is [`context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile, keyfile_password)`](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/src/paho/mqtt/client.py#L796); do the files (certfile/keyfile) referenced (with the really long names!) exist? Is the working directory as you expect (using a full path when debugging may help e.g. `/home/AV111/PyProj/projfolder/certs/a0...`).

Comment: @Brits, the keyfiles exist and I tried with the full paths too. Still the same error.

Comment: Please show the result of `ls -l certs` (assuming linux - want the contents of the certs folder). Your [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be more readable with shorter file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments the error you are seeing is triggered by a call to [`context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile, keyfile_password);`](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/src/paho/mqtt/client.py#L796) and indicates that one of the files (`certs/AmazonRootCA1.pem` and/or `certs/a0c9496....afd4f67f_certificate.pem.crt`) do not exist (this could possibly be permissions related).

To assist in showing the most likely cause I copied and ran your code with the same result:

```
python3 app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspaces/test/app.py", line 9, in <module>
    pub.tls_set("certs/AmazonRootCA1.pem", certfile = "certs/a0c94969f1e7d914d6fe54425d772e8d4611a4710d460e9f56374ea0afd4f67f_certificate.pem.crt", keyfile = "certs/a0c94969f1e7d914d6fe54425d772e8d4611a4710d460e9f56374ea0afd4f67f_private.pem.key")
  File "/usr/local/pip-global/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 796, in tls_set
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile, keyfile_password)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I then created the certificate file:

```bash
mkdir certs 
touch certs/a0c94969f1e7d914d6fe54425d772e8d4611a4710d460e9f56374ea0afd4f67f_certificate.pem.crt
```

and ran the app again (making no other changes):

```py
python3 app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspaces/test/app.py", line 9, in <module>
    pub.tls_set("certs/AmazonRootCA1.pem", certfile = "certs/a0c94969f1e7d914d6fe54425d772e8d4611a4710d460e9f56374ea0afd4f67f_certificate.pem.crt", keyfile = "certs/a0c94969f1e7d914d6fe54425d772e8d4611a4710d460e9f56374ea0afd4f67f_private.pem.key")
  File "/usr/local/pip-global/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 796, in tls_set
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile, keyfile_password)
ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:4044)
```

You will note that there is now a different error (the certificate now exists but is not a valid certificate). Adding a valid `crt` file will result in the `No such file or directory` error appearing again (due to an attempt to load the key file).

To complete the example I generated a [test certificate](https://en.rakko.tools/tools/46/) and put the certificate into `AmazonRootCA1.pem` and `a0c94969f1e7d914d6fe54425d772e8d4611a4710d460e9f56374ea0afd4f67f_certificate.pem.crt` and the key into `a0c94969f1e7d914d6fe54425d772e8d4611a4710d460e9f56374ea0afd4f67f_private.pem.key` and ran the app:

```
python3 app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspaces/test/app.py", line 10, in <module>
    pub.connect(broker, port)
  File "/usr/local/pip-global/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 914, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/usr/local/pip-global/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1044, in reconnect
    sock = self._create_socket_connection()
  File "/usr/local/pip-global/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 3685, in _create_socket_connection
    return socket.create_connection(addr, timeout=self._connect_timeout, source_address=source)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 823, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 954, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

This demonstrates that having valid certificates/key can result in the function completing successfully (it's now trying to connect to `alphanumeric-ats.iot.us-west-1.amazonaws.com` which will fail).

Your question does not provide sufficient information to do any further investigation; if you are still experiencing the issue try duplicating the process above and this will, most likely, assist in finding the cause.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Brits, this solved my issue. I went to amazontrusts and downladed a new rootCA and that fixed the error.